# Some users get "Internet explorer cannot display webpage" - How to debug?

Tags: internet-explorer

Some users of my website get the error message "Internet explorer cannot display webpage" when they visit the site. The users report that it's only this specific page that is having troubles. The troubles started at around the same time (3 weeks ago). It works fine in all other browsers, and it works for *most* IE users as well. I am unable to recreate the error myself with IE.

So, how on earth do I debug this? Most resources I've found regard how the users should fix their IE installation themselves, but ideally I would like to have a clearer image of what is going wrong before I ask users to go through procedures which may or may not fix their problem.

I understand this is a very vague question, but any debugging tips are welcome.

Comment: First of all: can you give us a link?

Comment: And what IE are you using? I tried with IE11, and it worked flawlessly. Which page is affected?

Comment: @Siyah: We have had users report the error on IE 7, 8 and 9. All pages on the site are affected, but the users report being able to visit other sites. I can't reproduce it myself (using IE9), which is what makes it so difficult to pinpoint.

Comment: So users have errors on all of those IE versions, but you can't see it? That's very very weird. I guess it has to do with their screen width's, in that case... I will try to reproduce it on IE 8 and 7, soon. You'll hear from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that recent changes by the hosting provider made the site require TLS 1.0. The affected users had that protocol disabled in their internet options.

Answer (score 1):

General questions get general answers. The problem here is that you have a page doing something which doesn't work in IE. Find out what that is first. Then decide weather this is a feature you need all users to have. If it is then you'll need to recreate that feature for IE users.